# D3.js - DOM text exiting incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, bar-chart

Here is my code - http://jsfiddle.net/kiniadit/dsmxtonL/

specific code -

```
var labels = svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset)
                    //Enter…
                      labels.enter()
                        .append("text")
                        .text(function(d) {
                            return d;
                        })
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .attr("x", w)
                        .attr("y", function(d) {
                            return h - yScale(d) + 14;
                        })
                       .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                       .attr("font-size", "11px")
                       .attr("fill", "black");

                    //Update…
            labels
              .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
              });

            //Exit…
            labels.exit()
              .remove();
```

I am unable to remove svg text elements correctly when I click the "Remove a data value" paragraph. The other DOM elements (svg rects) exit as they are supposed to but the svg text elements get deleted in a strange manner - the last data value (instead of the first) is removed.

This code is an almost an exact copy of http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_09/29_dynamic_labels.html from Scott Murray's book except that I use a regular array instead of a key-value object.

Please let me know what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: By default, `.data()` will try to match each element in the data with each element in the selection by index. So, if there are the same number of elements in the data as there are in the selection, no `enter` or `exit` selections will be created.

Comment: got it. so thats why the author was using a key. thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the example you cited that the data join is using a [key](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data):

```
// Create bars
svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset, key)
```

You can create a key pretty easily. Here's a sample to help get you going on what you're trying to achieve:

```
var length = dataset.length;

var key = function (d) { return d; };

var computeJoin = function() { 
  return svg.selectAll('rect').data(dataset, key);
}

var shiftDataset = function() {
  dataset.shift() 
  newItem.index = length; /* this index is unique */
  dataset.push(newItem)
  length = dataset.length; /* keep the length up to date */
}

var update = function() {
  labels = computeJoin(); /* join */

  /* enter, update, etc... */

  /* shift the data */
  shiftDataset()
  labels = join(dataset);
  labels.exit().remove();
}

/* init */
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  dataset[i].index = i;
}

/* update every 2000ms */
var DELAY = 2000;
setInterval( update, DELAY );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have simple error with your x values and y values calculation.
I have update your by correct some x and y values calculations.
It works OK, you can take a look here.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsmxtonL/3/)

To make it obvious, i change some style in you example,

```
.attr("fill", "black"); //update text label color to black
...
dataset[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + 14; // add 14 here as minum height of bars
```

Hope it helps. :-D